# SSRS Reporting project templates not available in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010, reporting-services

I am building SharePoint 2010 application using Visual Studio 2010 and the database is SQL Server 2008 R2, Enterprise version. Now I need to create SSRS reports in our application. I need to create a separate project for Reporting, but could find report project template and not even the business Intelligence section. Can someone guide me creating SSRS reports in specified environment and connect to SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create SSRS 2008 and SSRS 2008R2 projects, you'll be using BIDS (Business Intelligence Developer Studio), which runs in Visual Studio 2008.  If you install SQL 2012 Developer Tools, this integrates with Visual Studio 2010, and you can target SSRS 2008R2.  If you do not have access to 2012, you're stuck with VS2008.